# Session object null in servlet class but not in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I have this strange behavior in my application:
The session object obtained by the below statement on my servlet class is giving me null when deployed as a service on windows, but behaves fine when run on localhost. The same session object in JSP seems to work fine on localhost as well as deployed instance.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

This statement in JSP works fine:

```
<%String servervar =  (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("servername");
```

Note:When run as localhost I am not deploying as windows service, I am just running as "run on server" from my eclipse IDE

Could anyone suggest what could be the potential issue. Please let me know If I need to give more information

Comment: what do you mean *giving me null when deployed as a service on windows, but behaves fine when run on localhost?* where are you deploying your application in both case ?

Comment: When run as localhost I am not deploying as windows service, I am just running as "run on server" from my eclipse IDE